# "read more" in django posts

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am creating a blog on django/webfaction. Currently my home page displays all the contents from all the posts. I would like to tweak it to show only few lines from each post and each post ending with a "read more" link.  How to achieve this?  I am new to django and python. Kindly help me.

Code in home.html:

> ```
> {% block content %}
>
>   {% for post in object_list %}
>   <h2>{{ post.title }} </h2>
>
>   <div class = "post_meta">
>       on {{ post.created}}
>   </div>
>
>   <div class = "post_body">
>       {{ post.body|safe|linebreaks}}
>   </div>
>
>   {% endfor %}
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

You can use built-in template filter truncate [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatewords)

```
  <div class = "post_body">
      {{ post.body|safe|truncatewords:"50"|linebreaks }}
      <a href="{{ url_for_full_content }}">read more</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: How about the case when the length of the post less than 50 words?

Comment: @defuz you need judge the length of content first.

Comment: you can also use truncatechars

Comment: thanks! It worked. I assume my post will not be less than 50 words.

Comment: What if want the rest of the text to be displayed there in the div, without opening another page?

Comment: I know this is old, but in that case you can just create a modal, or a button with a js function in which you show '{{ post.body|safe}}'. I personally use the modals for that.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but here is how i solved this problem thanks to stackoverflow...

```
{% with text=post.body %}
        {% if text|wordcount > 56 %}
    <p class="half-content" id="half-{{ post.pk }}">{{text|safe|linebreaks|truncatewords:50}}<a data-id="{{ post.pk }}" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn"><br>Read more</a></p>
    <p class="full-content" id="full-{{post.pk }}" style="display: none;">{{ text|safe|linebreaks }}<a data-id="{{ post.pk}}" href="javascript:void();" class="show-hide-btn">Read less</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>
    {{ text|safe|linebreaks }}
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

this is the js code that you should add in your template also...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show-hide-btn").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#half-" + id).toggle();//hide/show..
    $("#full-" + id).toggle();
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see the implementation of the field model `SplitField` in [django-model-utils](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src/730c25fb8cbf/model_utils/fields.py#cl-178) extention:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.fields import SplitField

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = SplitField()

>>> a = Article.objects.all()[0]
>>> a.body.content
u'some text\n\n<!-- split -->\n\nmore text'
>>> a.body.excerpt
u'some text\n'
>>> unicode(a.body)
u'some text\n\n<!-- split -->\n\nmore text'
```

It correctly does exactly what you need. Read more in the [doc](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-model-utils#splitfield).

Comment: a dependency free way would be to write your own splitfield, but IMO  I don't think this should be model logic at all. It seems perfectly fine to use a custom templatetag here, hence this only has representational benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p  class="article-content ">{{ post.content|truncatewords:"35"|linebreaks }}</p>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO, please consider to [edit] your answer adding some extra informations.